# VMWare: copy Local file to Out of Band Controller server

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am having a ansible role to generate certificate for the ESXI hosts. The certificate is generated locally and I need to copy it to the OOB host of each server. The below ansible code will work but it is inappropriate.

```
- name: Copy new certificate and key to Server
  shell: |
    sshpass -p "{{esxi_password}}" scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@"{{ESXI_OOBHOST}}" 'mv /etc/vmware/ssl/my.key /etc/vmware/ssl/"$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"_my.key'
    sshpass -p "{{esxi_password}}" scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@"{{ESXI_OOBHOST}}" 'mv /etc/vmware/ssl/my.crt /etc/vmware/ssl/"$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"_my.crt'
    sshpass -p "{{esxi_password}}" scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -r ./certs/my.crt root@"{{ESXI_OOBHOST}}":/etc/vmware/ssl/my.crt 
    sshpass -p "{{esxi_password}}" scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -r ./certs/my.key root@"{{ESXI_OOBHOST}}":/etc/vmware/ssl/my.key 
    sshpass -p "{{esxi_password}}" scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' root@"{{ESXI_OOBHOST}}" 'services.sh  restart'
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: files_list
  no_log: true
```

I have tried to use "Delegate_to: ESXI_OOBHOST" and it is not working (as SSH Key of local is not added in the OOB host and can't be added as task is doing from Gitlab Runner).

```
-  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: ./certs/my.key
    dest: /etc/vmware/ssl/my.key
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0775
    backup: yes
  delegate_to: "{{ESXI_OOBHOST}}"
```

Is there any ansible module which can copy the file to the VMware hosts from local.

Answer (score 0):

I could copy a file to an ESXi host with the copy module.
The below is the playbook, inventory and test copy file I used.

```
% ls
example_playbook.yml    inventory       test_copy_file.txt
```

**example_playbook.yml**

```yaml
---
- name: Example Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Copy test file to ESXi host
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: ./test_copy_file.txt
        dest: /etc/vmware/ssl/test_copy_file.txt
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0775
      delegate_to: esxi-test04.homelab
```

**inventory**

```
[all]
esxi-test04.homelab ansible_user=root ansible_password=secret
```

**Execute the playbook**

I confirmed that there is no test file in ESXi host before executing the playbook.

```
[root@esxi-test04:~] ls /etc/vmware/ssl/ | grep test_copy_file.txt
```

Execute the playbook.

```
% ansible-playbook example_playbook.yml -i inventory
```

I confirmed that the test file can be copied.

```
[root@esxi-test04:~] ls /etc/vmware/ssl/ | grep test_copy_file.txt
test_copy_file.txt
```

BTW, My ESXi host version is 7.0.0.
Maybe we can find out something if you can provide the ansible log of your executed playbook with -vvv option.